# CloseActionScreenEvent is not working in LWC

Tags: quickaction, modal

I am working on a quick action button that triggers an Aura Component that contains a LWC. In this LWC I have a datatable with a column of buttons. When the user clicks on the button a Modal PopUp appears showing a form that contains two fields and a button to send this two fields to update. And once the record has being updated it brings me the id and in the javascript file I create a NavigationMixin to conduce the user to the updated record. So the url is saved in a lightning-formatted-url and when the user clicks on the bold text the record is open in a new window and it is supposed to close the LWC but this last thing is not working.

It should be easy there are some resources that made the same I did but I do not get where could be the problem.

My html:

```
<template>
<template if:false={showModalPopUp}>
    <lightning-card title="Puntos de producción cercanos" icon-name="custom:custom63"
    style="width:1000px;height:1000px">
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small" if:true={isLoading}> </lightning-spinner>
    <template if:true={hayDatos}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium" style="max-height:600px;height:400px">
            <div>
                <lightning-datatable class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked" key-field="id" data={records}
                    columns={columns} column-widths-mode='fixed' hide-checkbox-column="true" onrowaction={callAsignarSolicitudAction}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
            <template if:true={error}>
                {error}>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
    <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
    <template if:false={hayDatos}>
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="alignItems">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:warning" alternative-text="Warning!" ></lightning-icon>
                <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center " >
                    {mensajeDeSistema}
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>

<template if:true={showModalPopUp}>
    <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <template if:false={actualizacion}>
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <div class="slds-modal__header-button">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleModificarValores}>Modificar valores</button>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleEliminarAsignacion}>Eliminar asignación</button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close" title="Close">
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <template if:true={showForm}>
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">kwAsignado: {kwAsignado}</div>
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">kwDeseado: {kwDeseado}</div>

                        <lightning-input formatter="percent-fixed" type="number" step="0.01" label="Porcentaje asignado"  value={porcentajeAsignado} onchange={handlePorcentajeAsignado}></lightning-input>
                        <lightning-input formatter="percent-fixed" type="number" step="0.01" label="Porcentaje deseado"  value={porcentajeDeseado} onchange={handlePorcentajeDeseado}></lightning-input>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleEnviarParaModificar}>Modificar</button>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:true={actualizacion}>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="alignItems">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:warning" alternative-text="Warning!" ></lightning-icon>
                            <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center " >
                                <slot>
                                    <div> Los datos han sido modificados correctamente. Para visualizarlos acceda : <u><strong><lightning-formatted-url  value={url} onclick={handleCloseModal} label="aquí"  target="_blank"></lightning-formatted-url></strong></u>.</div>
                                </slot>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:true={hayMensajeError}>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <div>{mensajeProblemaParaActualizar}</div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    
</template>
```

Part of my js file:
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";

```
handleCloseModal(){
    this.showModalPopUp = false;
    console.log('funciona');
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({ bubbles: true, composed: true }));    
    console.log('No funciona');

}
```

And my xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target> 
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="recordId"  type="String" label="Record Id"  default="{!recordId}"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're housing the LWC inside an aura component? I suspect something is happening with the event due to this encapsulation.